# AppScript to replace image in google slides

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a gsheet appscript that replaces an image in google slide. Ultimately, i want to iterate through the spreadsheet and for each row create a new slide with the image of the row in the spreadsheet. Currently, I can't get it to work once.

My code is below:

```js
function updatePresentation() {
  // Replace with your actual presentation ID
  const PRESENTATION_ID = "My_ID"
  // Get the spreadsheet object
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Get data range (excluding header row)
  const dataRange = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().slice(1);
  
  // Access the Slides service
  const slidesApp = SlidesApp.openById(PRESENTATION_ID);
  
  // Get the template slide
  const templateSlide = slidesApp.getSlides()[0];
  const pageElements = templateSlide.getPageElements();
  Logger.log(pageElements)

  imageName = "test01.png"
  const imageBlob = DriveApp.getFilesByName(imageName).next().getBlob();

  const left = 0;   // The x-coordinate of the top left corner of the image
  const top = 0;    // The y-coordinate of the top left corner of the image
  const width = 200; // Width of the image
  const height = 100; // Height of the image
  
  // Add the image to the slide
  Logger.log(templateSlide.insertImage(imageBlob, left, top, width, height));

}
```

The current error message is
" Exception: The image you are trying to use is invalid or corrupt."

I've tried this a number of different ways with no success. Any help would be appreciated.